What is correct use of counter(), counter-increment() and counter-reset() with nested headings?
I am having some issues with counter-reset() when a div is added between the initial declaration and the reset.
I originally had something like this, with headings directly under the numberedHeadings class:


.numberedHeadings {
  counter-reset: heading1counter 0 heading2counter 0 heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
}

.numberedHeadings h1.chapterHeading {
  counter-reset: heading2counter 0 heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
  counter-increment: heading1counter;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.numberedHeadings h1.chapterHeading::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  content: counter(heading1counter) " ";
}


/* Repeat similar adjustments for h2, h3, and h4 */


/* Example for h2 */

.numberedHeadings h2.chapterHeading {
  counter-reset: heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
  counter-increment: heading2counter;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.numberedHeadings h2.chapterHeading::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  content: counter(heading1counter) "." counter(heading2counter) " ";
}
<div class="numberedHeadings">
  <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading one (should be 1)
  </h1>
  <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading two (should be 1.1)
  </h2>
  <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading three (should be 2)
  </h1>
  <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading four (should be 2.1)
  </h2>
  <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading five (should be 2.2)
  </h2>
  <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading 6 (should be 3)
  </h1>
  <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading 7 (should be 4)
  </h1>
  <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
    Heading 8 (should be 5)
  </h1>
</div>



Now I need to add an additional div container around each heading tag like this:


.numberedHeadings {
  counter-reset: heading1counter 0 heading2counter 0 heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
}

.numberedHeadings h1.chapterHeading {
  counter-reset: heading2counter 0 heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
  counter-increment: heading1counter;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.numberedHeadings h1.chapterHeading::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  content: counter(heading1counter) " ";
}


/* Repeat similar adjustments for h2, h3, and h4 */


/* Example for h2 */

.numberedHeadings h2.chapterHeading {
  counter-reset: heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
  counter-increment: heading2counter;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.numberedHeadings h2.chapterHeading::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  content: counter(heading1counter) "." counter(heading2counter) " ";
}
<div class="numberedHeadings">
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading one (should be 1)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading two (should be 1.1)
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading three (should be 2)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading four (should be 2.1)
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading five (should be 2.2)
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading 6 (should be 3)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading 7 (should be 4)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading 8 (should be 5)
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>



However I see that when this is done, although the counter-increment() is being fired, the counter-reset() is not.

When I run the first snippet in Google Chrome Version 123.0.6312.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10, the numbers after "should be" show up before the headings... Not sure what the issue is.

NOTE: the snippet here seems to work OK on Edge/Chrome (Windows10 tested) and Safari (IOS 16 tested). Not working properly on Firefox (124 Windows10).
.....................................................................
Bring the counter resetting/incrementing 'up' one level.
CSS :has can be used to sense which counter is involved.


.numberedHeadings {
  counter-reset: heading1counter 0 heading2counter 0 heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
}

.numberedHeadings .settingsControlGroup:has(h1.chapterHeading) {
  counter-reset: heading2counter 0 heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
  counter-increment: heading1counter;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.numberedHeadings h1.chapterHeading::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  content: counter(heading1counter) " ";
}


/* Repeat similar adjustments for h2, h3, and h4 */


/* Example for h2 */

.numberedHeadings .settingsControlGroup:has(h2.chapterHeading) {
  counter-reset: heading3counter 0 heading4counter 0;
  counter-increment: heading2counter;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.numberedHeadings h2.chapterHeading::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  content: counter(heading1counter) "." counter(heading2counter) " ";
}
<div class="numberedHeadings">
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading one (should be 1)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading two (should be 1.1)
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading three (should be 2)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading four (should be 2.1)
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h2 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading five (should be 2.2)
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading 6 (should be 3)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading 7 (should be 4)
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="settingsControlGroup">
    <h1 id="id-7adcf781-0be8-4536-8dd9-89d4553850cf" class="chapterHeading">
      Heading 8 (should be 5)
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>




Running the snippet, I still see the problem with headings "four" and "five".

Strange @Éric I see the correct 2.1 and 2.2. I’m on Edge/Windows 10, what are you using?

@A Haworth, I'm on Firefox 124 on Windows 10. Indeed, it is OK on Edge.

Weird, I was thinking it must be FFs late take up of :has but 124 should be OK. Hmm, will investigate.

Just to confirm that the snippet runs OK on Safari (IOS 16..)

@Éric yes, I've just tried on FF on Win10 and it has the bug, thanks for spotting. No idea why at the moment, I'll put a warning in the answer.

@AHaworth Thanks for your help. I have increased it to 4 levels haven't had the chance to test with FF Win10 yet though

Apparently this no longer works :( at least with chrome / edge windows 10. Must be due to an update
Tested with chrome: Version 126.0.6478.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Yes, I've just tried it on Windows 10 Edge and it does not work. How unpleasant. Still works on my Safari (IOS) tho'. Not sure what to suggest now.
